# numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are arranged in a row, find the number of rows in which the difference between two adjacent numbers is 1 or 2

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: When the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are arranged in a row, find the number of rows in which the difference between two adjacent numbers is 1 or 2.

My work: The way I did it is with mathematica12. The number was 56. Any other way?

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5,
7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6,
4}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 7,
5, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 6,
5, 7}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7}, {2, 1, 3, 4,
6, 7, 5}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4}, {2, 4, 6,
7, 5, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6}, {3, 1, 2,
4, 6, 5, 7}, {3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5}, {3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 2,
1, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6}, {4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 6,
7, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7}, {5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {5,
7, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2}, {5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {6,
4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7}, {6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4}, {6, 7, 5, 3, 4, 2,
1}, {6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1,
2}, {6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6}, {7, 5, 6, 4, 2,
1, 3}, {7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2}, {7, 5, 6, 4, 3,
2, 1}, {7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5}, {7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2}, {7, 6, 4, 5,
3, 2, 1}, {7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4}, {7, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1}, {7, 6, 5, 4,
2, 1, 3}, {7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2}, {7, 6, 5,
4, 3, 2, 1}}

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003274